# Inconsistency in MIME types for .py files

Tags: javascript, python, mime-types, mime

I am currently working on a file selector in js which should accept certain file types. Everything is working fine, except when it comes to Python files.

The way i'm handling accepting different types is by using MIME types. So for example, to accept excel files i'm setting `"application/vnd.ms-excel"`, which is working correctly.
Though, when I want to accept .py files, setting `"text/x-python"` does not suffice. I am aware that I can set accept to `".py"`, but in my case I want to specifically set the MIME tipe and not the file suffix. Furthermore, some python files seems to get the type `"text/plain"` which is another problem I am completely baffled of.

So, my question is: Why is it that python files seem to be handled somewhat differently from others? The MIME type should be consistent and enough to get the OS browser to show .py files.

Comment: OS browsers mostly use the file extension, not the MIME type

Comment: @mousetail Thanks for your comment. That is the frustrating part for me to understand, that some MIME types gets translated into accepted file extensions, while others do not.

Comment: Don't expect any `*/x-*` mime types to be detectable. IANA is the authority for mime types and python isn't listed (see [their list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)).

Comment: There are a huge variaty of datasets that attempt to translate between MIME types and extensions. They differ wildly in which extensions they support and how they encode them.

Comment: Thank you! Guess i'll have to go back with the tail between my legs and switch to file extensions instead